# Add storage to AWS batch job in Terrafrom

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-batch

I have a terraform code that create an EC2 type Batch job , and my aws batch job download some data a total of 50GB ,how to add that storage space to my instance in terrafrom ? and if there is another way to add that storage
This is my terrafrom code

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "pipeline" {
  compute_environment_name = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-compute-environment-${var.env}"

  compute_resources {
    instance_role = aws_iam_instance_profile.pipeline_batch.arn

    instance_type = var.pipeline_instance_type
    max_vcpus     = var.pipeline_max_vcpus
    min_vcpus     = 0

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.pipeline_batch.id
    ]
    subnets = var.subnets

    type = "EC2"
  }

  service_role = aws_iam_role.pipeline_batch_service_role.arn
  type         = "MANAGED"

  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_batch_job_queue" "pipeline" {
  depends_on = [aws_batch_compute_environment.pipeline]
  name       = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-job-queue-${var.env}"
  state      = "ENABLED"
  priority   = 1
  compute_environments = [
    aws_batch_compute_environment.pipeline.arn
  ]

  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "pipeline" {
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.pipeline]
  name       = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-job-definition-${var.env}"
  type       = "container"

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.pipeline.repository_url}:latest",
    "command": [ "--s3_bucket", "${var.input_bucket}", "--s3_upload_bucket", "${var.upload_bucket}"],
    "executionRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.pipeline_batch_instance_role.arn}",
    "memory": ${var.pipeline_memory},
    "vcpus": ${var.pipeline_vcpus}
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your terraform code / config & output when you try to apply it.

Comment: You could add an *EFS file system, access point & mount target* resources https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/efs_file_system , then in your container_properties you would add `"mountPoints": [{readOnly = null,containerPath = "/dir/path/", sourceVolume = YOUR-ACCESS-POINT-ROOT-PATH}]`

Comment: could you explain more because I did not get how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want you may be able to mount a shared EFS drive you could try something like this. Keep in mind I have not tested this & you will need to replace certain parameters with your **subnet-ids, vpc-id**, etc:

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "pipeline" {
  compute_environment_name = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-compute-environment-${var.env}"

  compute_resources {
    instance_role = aws_iam_instance_profile.pipeline_batch.arn

    instance_type = var.pipeline_instance_type
    max_vcpus     = var.pipeline_max_vcpus
    min_vcpus     = 0

    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.pipeline_batch.id
    ]
    subnets = var.subnets

    type = "EC2"
  }

  service_role = aws_iam_role.pipeline_batch_service_role.arn
  type         = "MANAGED"

  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_batch_job_queue" "pipeline" {
  depends_on = [aws_batch_compute_environment.pipeline]
  name       = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-job-queue-${var.env}"
  state      = "ENABLED"
  priority   = 1
  compute_environments = [
    aws_batch_compute_environment.pipeline.arn
  ]

  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "pipeline" {
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.pipeline]
  name       = "${var.product}-${var.application}-pipeline-batch-job-definition-${var.env}"
  type       = "container"

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.pipeline.repository_url}:latest",
    "command": [ "--s3_bucket", "${var.input_bucket}", "--s3_upload_bucket", "${var.upload_bucket}"],
    "executionRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.pipeline_batch_instance_role.arn}",
    "memory": ${var.pipeline_memory},
    "vcpus": ${var.pipeline_vcpus},
    "mountPoints": [
        {
          readOnly = null,
          containerPath = "/var/batch"
          sourceVolume = "YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM-NAME"
        }
      ]
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
  tags = {
    environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "general" {
  creation_token = "YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM-NAME"
  #kms_key_id = module.kms.arn
  #encrypted = true
  encrypted = false
  performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
  throughput_mode = "provisioned"
  provisioned_throughput_in_mibps = 8 
  tags = {Name = "YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM-NAME"}
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "general" {
  tags = {Name = "YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM-NAME"}
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.general.id
  root_directory { 
    path = "/YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM-NAME"
    creation_info {
      owner_gid = "1000"
      owner_uid = "1000"
      permissions = "755"
      }
    }
  posix_user {
    uid = "1000"
    gid = "1000"
  }
}

## FOR REDUNDANCY
## It is a good idea to add a mount target per AZ you use
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "a" {
  source = "app.terraform.io/popreach/efs-mount-target/aws"
  version = "1.0.0"
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.general.id
  subnet_id = PUBLIC-SUBNET-A
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.general.id]
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "b" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.general.id
  subnet_id = PUBLIC-SUBNET-B
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.general.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "general" {
  name = YOUR-SECURITY-GROUP-NAME
  vpc_id = YOUR-VPC-ID
  tags = {Name = YOUR-SECURITY-GROUP-NAME}
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  type = "ingress"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  from_port = "2049"
  to_port = "2049"
  protocol = "tcp"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.general.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  type = "egress"
  description = "egress"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  from_port = "0"
  to_port = "0"
  protocol = "all"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.general.id
}
```

You'll be able to mount your EFS drive on any EC2 Default AMZN Linux Instance like this: `mkdir /data/efs && mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport REPLACE_WITH_EFS_DNS:/ /data/efs`

Comment: I have a  python code that download the data so inside the python script I should add the code that mount efs file system?

Comment: yes, I believe so. I wasn't able to test, so you will have to test and verify. If my answer needs updating after you test, I will do that.